# implicit toString() call in sysout - unexpected behavior

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

My Program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
          char[] inputArr = "This will print as a sentence".toCharArray();
        System.out.println(inputArr);
        System.out.println("call --" + inputArr);
     }
}
```

[Ran here online](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php)

**Output:**

```
This will print as a sentence
call [C@138532dc
```

**Issue :** 
Why different behavior...I was thinking that **toString()** gets called in both instances

Comment: The println method is overloaded to take a char array as parameter and print its content.

Comment: Passing a char array to the `println()` method (case 1) is different from trying to concatenate its value to another string (case 2). 
As @ZouZou mentioned, the method is overloaded to be able to deal with it in case 1.